# Naming my tab for opening multiple websites?

Tags: javascript, html, batch-file

Hi I need some sciprt in any language but perhaps html or javascript or both because i can't understand them just a bit.you may use some bat files also if you want.

suppose the script opens three websites automatically :

http://www.gmail.com

http://www.google.com

http://www.yahoomail.co.in

then the tab of gmail can be according to me like **MyGmail** and the same goes for the rest of the websites, MyGoogle, MyYahooMail.

This is going to help me people and I know that it is going to be easy but I read some html and javascript 1 and half years ago but i can't remember anby of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code is in `JavaScript` which will open the 3 sites on page load. I hope this helps you.

```
window.onload = function(){

    var MyGmail = window.open("http://www.gmail.com");
    var MyGoogle = window.open("http://www.google.com");
    var MyYahooMail = window.open("http://www.yahoomail.co.in");

};
```

**Bookmarklet for the above script**

```
javascript:(function(){window.open("http://www.gmail.com");window.open("http://www.google.com");window.open("http://www.yahoomail.co.in");})();
```

Comment: I think the poster also wants the tab title to be as specified

Comment: another dumb question perhaps ?I should put it in a notepad and and save it with extension .js right

Comment: @munish - Yes, save it as `.js` file and use it in your html page.

Comment: @Joseph - The tab title will be set by the page itself which we cannot control.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't have any html code can you edit your answer and wrapp around some html code because I just put that code in notepad and opened the .js file thinking that it would open the websites

Comment: actually the tab title is also important because its also important for me as I need to identify those pages by tab name or I can do it if any other way yes I could use bookmark if it works me to identify that page when it opens somehow

Comment: @munish - Please check my edited answer I have added a bookmarklet, you can save it as a bookmark. It will open all the 3 required sites as soon as you open it. It is not possible to set the tab because the page itself sets the title which we cannot control.

Answer (score 1):

Another thing you can do is make a bookmark using the following code instead of a url

```
javascript:(function()window.open("http://www.gmail.com");window.open("http://www.google.com");window.open("http://www.yahoomail.co.in");})();
```